# Excel VBA Web Scraping - Object Required Error

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have a small piece of code which tried to search in a website and tells whether there are any results or not.

It works very good for me (@India) but not for my colleague (@US). He checked in 2 of his PCs but gets same error.

**After I click on search button, ie.Document becomes totally blank, also ie.Document.ChildNodes.Length returns 0.**

```
Sub iTest()
    Call ProcessRecord("First_Name", "Middle_Name", "Last_Name", "1/1/2015")
End Sub
Private Function ProcessRecord(fName As String, mName As String, lName As String, dob As String) As Boolean
    Dim results As String, idx%

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True

    Navigate ie, "http://ws.ocsd.org/ArrestWarrants/default.aspx"
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Loop
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Loop

    ' fill values in webpage
    ie.Document.getElementById("FirstName").Value = fName
    ie.Document.getElementById("MiddleName").Value = mName
    ie.Document.getElementById("LastName").Value = lName
    ie.Document.getElementById("DOB").Value = dob

    ' click on search button
    ie.Document.getElementById("btnSearch").Click

    ' wait for results
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Loop
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Loop

    ' check results
    results = ie.Document.getElementById("lblResults").innerText            '<< It gives Object Required error here. Because ie.Document has no element after I click on search button.

    If results = "No Results Found." Then
        MsgBox "Not found", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "Found", vbExclamation
    End If

    ie.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: Anybody to help here?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the below?

`Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
Loop`

Appears to be working for me, might just be a delay in internet connection for your US friend.

Comment: I already have this loop in my code. You have DoEvent which I don't have. Does it make any difference?